# Script to move folders with specific names and characters

Tags: powershell

I am looking to write a script that will move existing folders with a "-" hyphen in the name into a parent folder with part of the same name.

Example:

I would like to move c:\12345-01 into c:\12345\ to look like this c:\12345\12345-01.

The problem is the number of characters before the hyphen is not the same, they very from 3-6 characters before the hyphen. I have found a couple of snipets here and elsewhere that are close, but they won't work as they specify the number of characters in the file name

```
For Each objFile in objFolder.Files
    strName = Left(objFile.Name, 3)
```

this would work if all filenames were 3 characters.

Does that makes sense?

Answer (score 3):

```
cd 'C:\Directory\of\folder\where\number\files\located'
gci | ? {$_.PSIsContainer -eq $true} | % { `
    $file = $_.name
    $loc = $file.IndexOf('-')
    $folder = $file.substring(0,$loc)
    New-Item -Path . -ItemType Directory -Name $folder -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    move-item $file $folder
}
```

Comment: This partially worked..it moved all folders into thet parent folder. Including other parent folders. So now, I have only one folder.

Comment: Ah yea sorry, I originally wrote it for files and folders then realized I read your post wrong...

Answer (score 3):

You need to split the names on the delimiter. If you run the following from the root of the C drive, you'll get the structure you're looking for.

```
Get-ChildItem | where-object {
  ($_.PSIsContainer) -and ($_.Name.contains("-"))
} | foreach-object {
  new-item -itemtype Directory -path $($_.name.split("-")[0])
  move-item $_ -Destination $($_.name.split("-")[0])
}
```

Comment: Ok, progress....Alroc, this worked...however, I keep running into problems with existing folders. I try to add -force, but that doesn't help I get errors that int cannot create a file that already exists.     Get-ChildItem | where-object {
  ($_.PSIsContainer) -and ($_.Name.contains("-"))
} | foreach-object {
  new-item -itemtype Directory -path $($_.name.split("-")[0])
  move-item $_ -Destination $($_.name.split("-")[0]) -force
}

Comment: Just add `-ErrorAction SilentlyContinue` to the end of his `New-Item`.